# Prevent Url Tampering to access another users data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication, url-routing

I just wanted to gauge opinions on how I should approach this problem and ultimately looking for a quick win (wrong way to think about things nut time pressures mean I have to think and act quickly!

I've been given a website that has a bit of an issue.

I login using standard forms authentication as User1234 and my url is as follows:

www.mywebsite.co.uk/1234/Contact.

This will take me to User1234's details.

You can put two and two together and correctly assume that 1234 is a user id of some sort.

Once authenticated, I can access the views with [Authorize] attribute present, any anonymous/unathenticated users get redirected.

However, once logged in as User1234, I can then tinker with the url like so:

www.mywebsite.co.uk/1235/Contact.

So I am authenticated as User1234 but can see User1235's data. This is BAD for obvious reasons.

When I log in, I actively set the login ID in session so in theory, I could do a check whenever a user hits an ActionResult, I could cross check the ID present in the URL against the session login ID. However, it is a rather project with lots of action results and as such, I'm reluctant to spend my Saturday afternoon adding something to each and every ActionResult.

Is there an event in the global.asax I could use that is hit on each ActionResult request where I can compare Session login ID with url ID?

Alternatively, can anyone offer some suggestions about how I can achieve this or restrict URL tampering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you don't want to change your URL routes, as you could retrieve the user id also from the session. A quick solution would be to use an ActionFilter which you can place on the affected controllers or action methods:

```
public class VerifyUserIdAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var sessionUserId = filterContext.HttpContext.Session["UserId"];

        var routeUserId = filterContext.RouteData.Values["UserId"];
        if (routeUserId != null && sessionUserId == routeUserId)
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("<<url to redirect to>>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try and do a base controller

```
public class BaseController : Controller 
{
     protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        //Do your stuff here
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand why the URL contains a data entry point.  This appears to be a design flaw.    I would remove all code that uses a URL parameter and instead make sure the controller looks up what the ID is based on the logged in user.